# jquery, jqplot change option value

Tags: jquery

im using jquery: http://www.jqplot.com/ and i made a nice chart.
the only problem i got is this:
when im over 300 pixels of the chart, i want the highlighter tooltiplocation go's to 'nw' if its smaller its 'ne'.

current options:

```
  highlighter: {
       tooltipLocation: 'ne',
       useAxesFormatters: true,
   },
```

does anybody know how to change te location after its rendered?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to save the return value of jQPlot function in a variable:

```
targetPlot = $.jqplot(...your diagram...)
```

and can then set different options this way and replot:

```
targetPlot['legend']['location'] = "ne";
targetPlot.replot();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is explained very well here:
[Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/jqplot-users/browse_thread/thread/f993d8be36a7f747/df4712c077c97ea9)

You can use:

```
$("#your_jqplot_target").empty();
```

and create new

```
$.jqplot('...your diagram options here...');
```

in the same target (`your_jqplot_target`).

Like Sandro L said, if you save the return value of jQPlot function in a variable:

```
targetPlot = $.jqplot('...your diagram...');
```

Then you can set new series or options to it and `targetPlot.redraw();` or `targetPlot.replot();` it later. Please read more on the page linked above.